# Can I use tokens in Civi profile Cancel Redirect URL?

Tags: profile, redirect

Custom profile to edit a contact's activity.

Redirect URL is formed: **www.example.com/activities/{contact.id}** and works correctly.

I'd like to use the same redirect for Cancel Redirect URL.  Is it possible?  Are tokens supported in the cancel url or do I have to set a static page for cancel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that token availability is the exception rather than the rule.  You shouldn't expect tokens to be replaced in the redirect URL.

Comment: I don't expect them but are delighted when they're there!  Seems strange that one redirect works and one doesn't though.